# Trying to write a long set in curly braces where the set is going to be two rows

Tags: arrays

I'm basically trying to recreate this:

[image: set notation]

I've tried creating an array and using the `\left` and `\right` commands but I keep getting the error:
"`\left` can only be used in math mode" So I was wondering if I even need to use an array or do I use another command?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex.SE. Please provide your code, otherwise people will not be able to find the source of your error.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a message that `\left` can only be used in math mode, that means you're not in math mode. So have you enclosed the whole of what you're working in `\[`…`\]`?

I would be inclined to do this as:

```
\[
S=\left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
  1324, 3124, etc.\\
  2314, 2341, etc.
  \end{array}
\right\}
\]
```

Comment: Thank you! So is math mode enabled by the braces?

Comment: If you mean the `\[`…`\]`, yes.